# Table paragraph column does not seem to work properly (& caption issue)

Tags: tables, captions, wrap

Quite new to LaTeX, everything was going fine until tables!

My document class is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
```

And I'm trying to insert this table into it:

```
\begin{table*}

\begin{tabular}{| c | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | c | c | c | c | p{4cm} |}
    \hline
    Strain & Mean log growth of Control & NG difference & Standard Error & t value & p value  & Mutation known to be be via. (Montano 2012 pers. comm.) \\ \hline
    421    & 6.29                       & -2.17         & 0.47           & -4.63   & 0.00002  & Missense                                                \\ \hline
    712    & 4.93                       & -3.23         & 1.53           & -2.11   & 0.038888 & Deletion                                                \\ \hline
    881    & 2.54                       & 3.14          & 0.71           & 4.42    & 0.00005  &  Missense causing nonsense mutation  (amber)            \\ \hline
    899    & -0.98                      & 7.37          & 1.99           & 3.71    & 0.00047  &  Missense                                               \\ \hline
    TA102  & 4.84                       & 1.42          & 0.57           & 2.47    & 0.01638  & Missense causing nonsense mutation  (ochre)             \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\caption Class data statistics

\end{table*}
```

The end result is a final column that does not seem to be wrapping and a caption which is wrapping in a very peculiar fashion:

[image: compilation result]

Comment: I've had this problem and fixed it by adding a dummy final column.

Comment: the mutation column seems to have `c` formatting not `p{4cm}` you may want to use `\begin{tabular}{| c | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | c | c | c | p{4cm} |}`

Comment: Tried adding a dummy column to no avail... Doesn't change a thing (as far as I can see, as most of the table is still off the edge of the page)

Comment: Yeah.  I'm trying to figure out why that's not working now. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have too many `c|` in the middle, you only have 7 columns of data but 8 column specifications so your final column is using a `c` and so does not wrap, rather than use  the intended `p{4cm}`

`\caption` takes an argument so should be

```
 \caption{Class data statistics}
```

As you have it the caption argument is just `C`

Comment: D'oh fantastic that sorted it, I knew it would be something ridiculously simple that I'd overlooked...

Comment: The caption is still formatted in the same strange way though however.

Comment: @Ben use `\caption{Class data statistics}` to fix the caption. The `caption` command is picking up only the first non whitespace letter (in this case C)

Comment: Thanks, a lot, I feel like such a clutz asking simple questions- but I guess that's how you learn!